# how to make an exchange of messages between two different computers in the same network?

Tags: jolie

How can have the simple exchange of message between two different computer

code of interface is:

```
interface MyInterface{
    RequestResponse: Doppio(int)(int)
}
```

code of client is:

```
include "MyInterface.ol"
include "console.iol"

outputPort B {
    Location: "socket://192.168.1.145:8000"
    Protocol: http
    Interfaces: MyInterface
}

main{
    Doppio@B(5)(response);
    print@Console(response)()
}
```

code of server is:

```
execution { concurrent }

include "MyInterface.ol"

inputPort B {
Location: "socket://192.168.1.145:8000"
Protocol: http
Interfaces: MyInterface
}

main {
 Doppio(x)(Dop)
    { 
        Dop=x*2
    }
}
```

the code works because is the same PC and same IP address, but with 2 PC (with their IP address) doesn't work!
for me the problem is the socket but I don't know, help me please

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a temptative answer, I need to know, at least, two things:

- basic network setup;
- error message from the execution of the commands `jolie server.ol` and `jolie client.ol`.

**Tip**: pick an IP address of a different device connected to the same network, such as `192.168.1.xxx`, and provide the result of `ping 192.168.1.xxx`. Also, the network/firewall should allow for incoming connections to the port you would choose (for instance 8000, as in the code snippet above).